# how do I phrase this sentence formally?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, formal-language

The email me thanking the recipient for offering me a work experience placement. I would like to ask for the recipient of my email to tell me more details about the placement closer to the time . However I don't know how to phrase it. Please help.

I was thinking something along the lines of "please keep me informed" but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find anything wrong with "please keep me informed," but it might sound better if you add a prepositional phrase with *about*.

> Thank you for offering me this work experience placement. Please keep me informed about this.

or even:

> Thank you for offering me this work experience placement. Please keep me informed about this as you get more information.

If you wanted to be a little more informal, you could say:

> Thank you for offering me this work experience placement. Please keep me posted.

<sub>As a footnote: I'm in the US; I'm not sure if "Please keep me posted" sounds acceptable in the UK or other locations.</sub>

Comment: Also, in the US, "work experience placements" are typically called paid|unpaid *internships*. Sometimes the unpaid internships offer some kind of travel or commuting stipend, so it would not be out of line to inquire about that possibility.

Answer (score -1):

I usually go with "Please keep me appraised" if I want to be kept updated. Its sounds formal.

Comment: "appraised", or "apprised"?

Comment: It should be apprised.

Answer (score -1):

> "keep me posted/informed/updated"

these are the most sensible and natural ways of expressing the need to be informed about the situation.